# PHP Array with implode not translating correctly inside php postgresql query

Tags: php, postgresql

I have an array that when imploded with the appropriate syntax is formatted correctly. That is to say that it tests perfect in PGAdmin. However, when I try to display use the variable in my query it is changing the characters. Here is my code:

Posted from HTML Form:

```
$media= $_POST["userMedia"];
```

implode:

```
$media_names = "'".implode( "%','", $media)."%'";
```

dump of $media_names:

```
string(25) "'COMM_7029%','COMM_7030%'"
```

What $media_names looks like in query error:

```
 m.name LIKE any (array[''COMM_7029%','COMM_7030%''])
```

I tried to eliminate the first " ' " from implode, but this was the resulting string dump:

```
string(24) "COMM_7029%','COMM_7030%'"
```

The rest of the code:

User Form from which data is selected for POST:

```
<select multiple name="userMedia" class="form-control" id="userMedia[]" style="height:350px;">
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("dblogin");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT medias.name FROM public.medias where medias.startdate >  '2015-01-01'";
$rs = pg_query($conn, $sql);


if (pg_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
$menu .= "<option value=".$row['name'].">" . $row['name']. "</option>";
}
}

echo $menu;

pg_close($conn); 

?> 
</select>
```

PHP for Database Query:

```
$datea= $_POST["userDatea"];
$media= $_POST["userMedia"];
$datez= $_POST["userDatez"];
$media_names = "'".implode( "%','", $media)."%'";


var_dump($media_names);

 if( !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post')===0)  ) {
// Create connection
$conn = pg_connect("dbconnect");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}
$result = pg_query($conn,
"SELECT
date (b.starttime),
Count(b.starttime) as Plays,
Count(distinct(b.playerid)) as Stores

FROM
public.billing b,
public.medias m,
public.players p

WHERE
b.mediaitemid = m.id and
p.id = b.playerid and
m.name LIKE any (array['$media_names']) and
b.starttime >= date('$datea') and 
b.starttime < date('$datez')+1 and
m.startdate >  '2015-01-01'

GROUP BY
date (b.starttime)

ORDER BY
date (b.starttime);");

if (!$result) {
echo "Query failed.\n";
exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that actually is ran for us to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

I removed the single quotes around $media_names in the query and it returned the data as expected.

Changed from:

```
m.name LIKE any (array['$media_names'])
```

to this:

```
m.name LIKE any (array[$media_names])
```